# How to set the event when i click the pagination in datatable plugin in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I used the Data Table jQuery plugin and I have to trigger the event when i will click the pagination in the Data Table plugin.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [page](http://datatables.net/reference/event/page) event that will be fired when page is changed, whether it's by user clicking the pagination control, selecting different page length or using DataTables API.

See the example below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example').on('page.dt', function(){
    var info = table.page.info();
    console.log( 'Showing page: '+info.page+' of '+info.pages );
});
```

Comment: This code only works for pagination, if page length changes then it does not work